# WP Category Page Order posts on Custom Field and date

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

In my WP website I have several categories, each category has posts from a community and on each post is 1 adress of a hotel.

In these categories I must have two blocks (must be in the same category) the first block we name group1, the second block is group2.

When clicking on the category page, the visitor see first all posts from group1 and direct after that the posts from group2.

What I already have done:

I take a Custom field named Groups and placed in the value 1 (for group 1) or 2 (for group 2)

In my Category page I have placed this code above

```
<?php while ( have posts() ...

<?php if (is_category('saalbach-hinterglemm')) { $posts = query_posts($query_string. '&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=Groups&order=ASC' ); } ?>
```

Now the stupid thing, everything runs ok except the date order of the posts, I tried the order ASC to change to DESC and the only change is the difference that group1 comes first or in the other case Group2 but in both cases always the oldest post at first place (not the newest.... please can somebody help me with this?

Comment: do you have some code you've tried so far?

Comment: Yes this one 

<?php if (is_category('saalbach-hinterglemm')) { $posts = query_posts($query_string. '&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=Groups&order=ASC' ); } ?>

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding `date` to the `orderby`:

```
'&orderby=date,meta_value&meta_key=Groups&order=ASC'
```

Comment: Now didn´t help does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress `WP_Query` doesn't support multiple values for the `order` parameter ( your query arguments should be  `&orderby=meta_value,date&meta_key=Groups&order=ASC,DESC` )

You can try using `posts_orderby` filter ([codex link here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby)).

Put this code into your functions.php file:

```
function enforce_specific_order($orderby) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->prefix."postmeta.meta_value ASC, ".$wpdb->prefix."posts.post_date DESC";  
}
```

Then modify your code as this:

```
<?php if (is_category('saalbach-hinterglemm')) { 
     add_filter('posts_orderby', 'enforce_specific_order'); 
     $posts = query_posts($query_string. '&meta_key=Groups' );
     remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ ); 
 } ?>
```

Comment: I m sorry but i do not have the knowledge op php, i do nut understand how to impliment this code

Comment: THANKS THAT DID THE JOB THANK YOU THANK YOU andreivictor

Comment: Hello andreivictor, i have two questions, at first howto mark the answer as acepted and my second question: suppose to work with a parent category Saalbach-hinterglemm and have two child categories we named here childcategory red and another childcategory blue is here a big diference to make a filter that on the categorypage "saalbach-hinterglem at first all the posts from childcategory red are listed and afterwahrts al the posts from childcategory blue (also each with the sorting of the date?)